# Inside join make if condition and get details in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I tried to match two columns and if it was matching based on the id i'll assign username to that matched column. but inside join i can't make if condition on  joining table.

```
  $list = DB::table('job')
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'job.created_by')
      ->select('job.*','users.first_name as created_by','users.first_name')
      ->where('job.enterprise_id', $user->id)
      ->get();
```

In my json i had one value updated_by with value 1 means i can match with  id column if it was matching i will display updated_by = first_name otherwise updated_by = null.

Comment: make raw query of your need and then we'll convert it

Comment: that one i tried already it was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the name of user who updated job you can use a left join to users table.

```
$list = DB::table('job as j')
        ->join('users as u1', 'u1.id', '=', 'j.created_by')
        ->leftJoin('users as u2', 'j.updated_by' , '=', 'u2.id')
        ->select('j.*','u1.first_name as created_by','u2.first_name as updated_by')
        ->where('j.enterprise_id', $user->id)
        ->get();
```

If job was updated `u2.first_name` will return the name of user who updated that job if job is not update you will have a null value against `u2.first_name`. Also i assume you job table has a column named as `updated_by` which stores this information.

Comment: i had one small doubt dude inside one column - created_at = 2017-07-17 20:47:02 like this but i need to show only date

Comment: @SivarajuMani Its better if you format you datetime value in application code , Doing in Mysql is not a good idea , You use helper classes like `Carbon` or php's Datetime